# Двойное нажатие на кнопку вместо одного! ASP + Button

Tags: asp.net, c#

**Добрый день!**

делаю форму для комментариев, привязал к БД, вроде все ок.
только чтобы комментарий добавился, т.е. чтобы ИСПОЛНИЛСЯ код кнопки "Доабвить", нужно нажать на эту кнопку ДВАЖДЫ! В первый раз с таким сталкиваюсь,

***Подскажите, где я не прав?*** 
кидаю код всей панельки.

```
        <asp:Panel ID="PanelAddNewComment" runat="server" 
            BackImageUrl="~/Pictures/quilt.png" Height="233px" ScrollBars="Auto" 
            Width="465px">
            <strong><span class="style2" style="text-decoration: underline">Оставьте 
            комментарий:<br /> </span></strong>
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="tb_NewCommentText" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                BorderStyle="Groove" BorderWidth="1px" Height="116px" MaxLength="500" 
                style="margin-top: 0px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="391px"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="btnAddNewComment" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
                onclick="btnAddNewComment_Click" Text="Добавить комментарий" Width="187px" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnClearCommentText" runat="server" 
                onclick="btnClearCommentText_Click" Text="Очистить комментарий" />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lb_OuttextToComment" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
                Font-Names="Georgia" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="#CC0066" 
                Text="Ваш комментарий будет добавлен на сайт после модерации. Спасибо за отзыв!" 
                Visible="False"></asp:Label>
        </asp:Panel>
```

Другая же кнопка отрабатывает также со второго нажатия.

Answer (score 1):

Уберите

> AutoPostBack="True"

из определения TextBox-a.